# Is there a local Google App Engine data viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to use google's online GAE data viewer offline...
Is there some bunch of python code to display all my local data and even schema?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, go to http://localhost:8000/_ah/admin (supposing you're running your local instance with dev_appserver.py).

*NOTE*: when the app is being deployed locally, it logs to which port the admin page is being binded

Comment: oh, that is excellent, so from which link I can get info on things I can do locally? I have seen Interactive and memcahce already... cool...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#The_Development_Console