# Local Datastore Editor

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm stuck trying to figure out a way to edit my local datastore within the Java SDK.  Is there some kind of interactive interface (command line or GUI) that will allow me to modify data to help with testing and scenario creation?

The online datastore editor is awesome in the new Cloud Console, you can add fields, edit data, define field types, etc.  I've tried to find something similar locally, but I have had little success as most things are defunct, abandoned, or hard to use.

Am I missing something?  Or does this simply not exist?

***This is not a feature request.  I want to make sure I'm not missing something.  I'll file a feature request if I find out what I'm looking for simply doesn't exist.***

Comment: If what you're doing is a Feature Request.... you're on the wrong website to do it. Go to Google's App Engine's issue list for that :) : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: Thanks, but not a feature request. Google suggests always starting on the StackOverflow forum for advice or help, so that's where I started. I'll definitely file a feature request if this continues to get no response here.  It's a shame someone downvoted this because I'm following the process that is proposed, and I'm asking if there are any solutions such as AppWrench (now defunct) that I may have missed.

Comment: the downvote probably comes because, while you respect Google's process, this is still not a valid Stack Question. I read on this site by a Googler that they will phrase their redirect differently so it doesn't all land here.  In the meantime, asking for "I want the local datastore editor to do the same things the online one does" kinda sounds like a Feature Request.

Comment: I'll figure out a way to phrase it as a question and not a feature request. Inane, but if it appeases the masses...

Comment: I added an answer with my research as well to help anyone else with the same question.  Heading over Google to file a feature request now.  Thanks for the help @Patrice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bunch of research and searched through myriad StackOverflow posts as well as combed the Internet for a couple days.  The following are my notes.

At this point, this is looking like a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11653).  Star it if you too would like this feature.

The options currently available that I've found are as follows:

- [Local Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624335/4143245) - works for viewing data and deleting rows, doesn't allow editing/adding data or looking at data types
- [appcfg.py](http://littleq.logdown.com/posts/2014/03/19/right-way-to-download-app-engine-and-deploy-it-to-development-server) - Edit online, then download_data/upload_data (this is what we're currently doing)
- [gaecl](https://github.com/inpun/gaecl) - limited functionality, editing of data is cumbersome but you might be able to script it
- [remote_api_shell.py](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) - seems to work well if you are using Python on GAE, otherwise it's only moderately helpful (or you have to duplicate some of your Entity definitions)

Things I've found that appear defunct or don't really fit the local datastore editing features most developers would desire:

- [AppWrench](http://appwrench.onpositive.com/) - probably the closest to what I wanted, but no longer supported and doesn't appear to work with the latest Eclipse/AppEngine-SDK
- [AppEngine-Admin](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/) - no longer in development or supported
- [AppEngine-Admin](https://github.com/humble/appengine_admin) (fork) - no longer in development or supported
- [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/) - this pretty much assumes you want to roll your own GAE, which seems like a big decision just for datastore editing (off topic, out of scope)

*If you add other solutions (good or bad) in the comments below I will update this answer.  It'll help me when filing the feature request.*